# SSL setup on BOA 2.2.5

Tags: aegir

I am trying to use https for my website hosted using BOA 2.2.5, I am following this documentation:

http://community.aegirproject.org/content/content/administrator/post-install-configuration/using-ssl

The problem is after following the steps for Configure Your Aegir Server, I can't find the directory that it said would be created:

/var/aegir/config/ssl.d

/var/aegir/config/server_master/ssl.d

Answer (score 0):

We don't recommend the built-in Aegir SSL feature (yet), as explained in [BOA docs](https://github.com/omega8cc/boa/blob/master/docs/SSL.txt).

Anyway, on BOA/Octopus, the directory you are looking for is located in the /data/disk/USER/config/ tree.